# Using the height of another element

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to get a jQuery slider to use the percentage height of a div.

The usual code in my HTML page is:

```
window.f = new x.slider('#slider1', {...options...});
```

And the .js:

```
x.slider = function(elem, opts)
...
var _this = this;
this.element = $(elem);
this.height = this.options.height ? this.options.height : null;
```

My question is, rather than using "this" to get the height from, how would I get it from another div, say "#basis"?

I've tried a few things, but I'm new to jQuery, and this is only a quick problem.
Thank you for your help. Please do tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use jQuery's `height` method:

```
$('#basis').height();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdwEM/

Comment: @Jordan please, click the green tick of Joseph's answer, because he solved your issue.

Comment: @Gabriel Santos - Will do. Just have to wait a few minutes, I'm told.

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
$("#basis").height();
```

See http://api.jquery.com/height/